Is Rabi cycle a coupling of laser-atom as two resonators? Are photons travelling in both directions there?
Trying to understand Rabi cycle, I thought it resembles coupled pendulums/resonators like in the animation - wanted to ask if it is appropriate analog?

laser is large pumped directional resonator,
atom is tiny isotropic resonator,
they are coupled with EM field.

If so, such laser-atom coupling of resonators causes energy exchange periodically in both directions, with photons traveling between them left and right.
Are photons traveling both laser $\rightarrow$ atom, and atom $\leftarrow$ laser in Rabi cycle?
If so, could we block one of them e.g. with optical isolator? (like removal of backward ASE in optical amplifiers)


Update: there are many arguments it is true like below, I haven't seen any counterarguments (?) - but if indeed Rabi cycle requires photons traveling in both directions, e.g. for synchrotron radiation it seems not possible (?)
And indeed for free electron laser, while damped Rabi requires $N_2 \to N/2$, https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04948-y observes $N_2 \to \approx N$ nearly complete excitation:

Also optical isolator should block such two-directional photon exchange required for Rabi, and turns out most of lasers have built-in optical isolator - searching for ways they obtain Rabi, seems it requires tricks now:

delivering beam from both sides e.g.
https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/0801.4126  or https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/physics/articles/10.3389/fphy.2024.1405149/full :



adding "reference resonator" e.g. in  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1049250X0380006X

I suspect just removing the optical isolator built in laser, should allow for Rabi cycle with single beam, without such tricks - could anybody confirm or deny?


Are photons traveling both laser atom, and atom laser in Rabi cycle?

Yes, we can see this effect through the Jaynes-Cummings model. We can see that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian of System+Field are superpositions of states $|g,n\rangle$ and $|e,n-1\rangle$. But more than that, even if the field is in a coherent state, whose number of photons is not well defined, we could observe collapse and revival of oscillations of the system.

I can't answer if this is a good analogy. Starting from the Classical Rabi problem, we have the driven dumped harmonic oscillator, not two oscillators, being the classical version of the Rabi problem. I understand, however, that this approach does not consider the possibility of the system to transfer energy to the field, which is a present effect in the quantum version.
The question if we could block them is a good one. I know that Ramsey interferometry uses the effect of Rabi oscillations to realize quantum operations, controlling the state of the atom with high precision. These interferometers have non-interaction zones, where the atom and the field could not exchange energy. The time inside in the cavities (interaction zones) are well adjusted to produce the desired superposition states (similar what we do in other interferometers, like the Mach-Zehnder with beam splitters with well adjusted transmission coefficient). In this sense, the non-interaction zones of a Ramsey interferometer do something similar of what you are asking.

Maybe you could check the experiments where people explore the transition from classical to quantum regime of Ramsey interferometer, like this one. Another interesting reference is this article, where the authors explore the effect of dissipation under the field in the interferometer. It is really interesting to figure out why we could see the energy going from the field to the system and back in the quantum regime, but it seems to not happen in the classical regime.

Thank you for the answer and lots of references - I will study them. Being able to introduce asymmetry in its energy transfer could lead to interesting new applications ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/2409.15399 ) - please let me know if you could think of something. Synchrotron radiation allows for that, and I hope also optical isolator  - it blocks optical photons being localized EM waves, but there should be also coupling through delocalized EM waves it shouldn't affect (?) - like in vacuum Rabi oscillations of energy between being localized in atom, and delocalized as optical cavity standing wave.
